# How to use webforms MasterView in MVC project?

Tags: inheritance, model-view-controller, view, webforms

I have two projects in one solution. One is based on Web Forms with a MasterView and on the other hand i have an MVC Project. I integrate MVC project with WebForms with the help of reference but the problem is i can't use WebForms master view i.e "main.Master" with mvc project views. i have followed some links but didnt find the solution.

I did this way to target the main.Master page but didn't work for me.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ERP_UI/main.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

and by using this line in layout.aspx i am getting this error.

```
Type 'ASP.main_master' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase'.
```

Is there any solution to use WebForms master view in mvc project ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no good way of doing this.  However there are some useful things you can do depending on what you want to display.  If you edit you answer indicating what you want your master page to do (e.g. just static content, getting content from database etc) people might be able to make some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @DaveBarnett, I already solved it by converting the vb master page in to the normal MVC master page. Also have created the new classes for dynamic content.